# levenshtein mysql procedure alternative in php

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any alternate for Levenshtein procedure written in mysql.?
I have changed my hosting server but unfortunately my new hosting don't facilitate with stored procedures. I have two stored procedures in the old server[image]

So I need to write some alternative way i.e in PHP for the above levenshtein MySQL functions.

Comment: ... php.net/levenshtein

Comment: In lieu of stored procedures (regardless of type) you should create functions in PHP that provide you with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a built in `levenshtein` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php